# Count data with 2 conditions on same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Here is my sample table:

```
owner        file_type       status
John            doc_1           1  
John            doc_2           1   
John            doc_3           0
Mike            doc_1           1
Mike            doc_2           0
Mike            doc_3           1   
Dona            doc_1           0   
Dona            doc_2           0
Dona            doc_3           0  
Jane            doc_1           1   
Jane            doc_2           1
Jane            doc_3           1
```

Result I need to see from my query is this:

```
owner        uploaded       remaining
John            2               1  
Mike            2               1  
Dona            0               3   
Jane            3               0
```

Here is the code I tried.

```
SELECT owner AS 'Name', COUNT(file_type) AS 'uploaded'
FROM sampleTable
WHERE [status] = 1
GROUP BY owner
```

Based on my code I get the count of uploaded documents,but how do I also get the remaining count in the same query the other condition is `[status] = 0`?

Answer (score 2):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    owner AS Name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS uploaded,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 END) AS remaining
FROM sampleTable
GROUP BY owner
```

Each of the above `CASE` expressions conditionally counts the number of times the status be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  owner [Name], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN file_type = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) uploaded,
        SUM(CASE WHEN file_type = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) remaining
FROM sampleTable 
GROUP BY owner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `status` is always `0` or `1`, I would recommend arithmetics rather than `case` expressions. I would assume this solution to be a little more efficient than the `case` approach (and it also neater):

```
SELECT owner AS name, SUM(status) uploaded, SUM(1 - status) remaining
FROM sampleTable
GROUP BY owner
```

Comment: Status might be a `bit` and SUM won't work.